# Visual Studio Web Deployment for Multiple Project Solutions

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, web-deployment

We've recently started using the Web Deployment method offered in Visual Studio.  For projects that have a single project in each solution, the deployment works fine and all files are copied correctly to the IIS server.

However, we have some solutions that have multiple projects in them.  (2 or 3 projects...never any more than that.)  There is a main project and some additional sub-projects.  When the deployment happens, all the source .aspx and .cs files from the main project are copied to the server as well as all the output files in the bin directory, however the .aspx and .cs files from the sub-projects are not being copied to the server.

How can I get the deployment process to include the other supporting files in the sub-projects?

Comment: Are the other projects executable or are they libraries?

Comment: They are libraries